# Write out api object from fetch to html

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

I'm trying to get my code to output an api object to the html file.

```
const container = document.createElement('div');
container.setAttribute('class', 'container');


obj = fetch('https://apis.is/concerts')
.then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
})
.then(function(data) {
    return obj = data;
})
.then(() => idk()) 

    function idk() {
    let count = 0;
        for(key in obj.results) {
            count++;
        };
        console.log(count);
        for(let i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            const card = document.createElement('div');
            card.setAttribute('class', 'card');

            const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
            h1.textContent = obj.results[i].eventDateName;

            const p = document.createElement('p');
            p.textContent = obj.results[i].dateOfShow;

            container.appendChild(card);
            card.appendChild(h1);
            card.appendChild(p);
        };
    };
```

I have been trying to use DOM to create elements for the html file but it's like some of the code is being ignored.

Comment: And which bit of the code would that be?

Comment: The idk function

Comment: I can't see the bit where you append the container to the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to render all the DOM you are creating you have to somehow add it to the DOM tree that browser is displaying. The simples way would be to add it to body node. `document.querySelector('body').appendChild(container);` once you're done with data processing.

But I would suggest to refactor your code a bit. For instance in this step you are assigning results to the original object where you are saving the promise with the results. Also that is a global object so pretty quick you might end up with a race condition.

`.then(function(data) {
    return obj = data;
})`

Also the idk() function is coupled to that very specific variable obj which would make it really hard to test.

```
obj = fetch('https://apis.is/concerts')
.then(function(response) {
    return response.json(); //subscribe to response stream
})
.then((response) => {
  const allEvents = eventsDomTree(response.results); // create the events DOM tree based on response
  document.querySelector('body').appendChild(allEvents); //append the created list to document DOM tree
});

  function eventsDomTree(events) {
    const allEvents = document.createElement('div');
    events.forEach((event) => {
      const card = document.createElement('div');
      card.setAttribute('class', 'card');

      const eventName = document.createElement('h1');
      eventName.textContent = event.eventDateName;

      const dateOfShow = document.createElement('p');
      dateOfShow.textContent = event.dateOfShow

      card.appendChild(eventName);
      card.appendChild(dateOfShow);

      allEvents.appendChild(card);
    });
    return allEvents;
  }
```